# Integrating My Application with Powerpoint

Tags: c, opencv, user-interface, gesture

I have developed small basic gesture application using OpenCV. So is it possible to integrate my gesture application with MS Powerpoint or any other software like VLC.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible by creating some kind of driver for a virtual device which will broadcast events according to Your gestures, like "mouse scroll wheel up" or sth. You would need to dig in to MS api for this, and probably this would be a lot more work than Your gesture recognition app. On the other hand, might be some kind of software like this available already.